# Adjust opacity of a forms background without changing the input

Tags: css, opacity

I'm trying to recreate something like [this](http://www.awwwards.com/gallery/4096/3) for one of the forms on my site by using opacity to make the form field background only 20% visible, but when I do this it also affects the text on the inside, and when you type something in. How can I make the opacity apply only to the background?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

opacity will always affect all included (child) tags. You may put 1px png image with required color and 20% visibility in background (or, if that is some image there, not jus solid color - change alpha for the whole image). And looks like that is what you need (I finally understood that I should look at image instead of site design available by your link))

Another option is to put some div with opacity below other tags using css position, z-index etc. But in this case there should be one, for instance, div which contains all your content that should not be transparent and another div with opacity near it

Comment: How can I change the alpha for the whole image? I made a 1px white background but I don't know how to apply the opacity to just the background. If I use opacity attribute it makes it all opacity and I can't see my text.

Comment: Depends on your tool. I'm using GIMP for manipulation with images. But that is not my strong side. I can't say how that could be done even if I did such things few times) But it seams to me that you missundertood me. That 1px image already must be transparent. And than you do not need to put any opacity. Just transparent PNG with required color

Answer (score -1):

Give a different class for the Field and Make opacity for field 100%

Comment: this will not work. All child elements will have the same opacity as parent div. field must be located outside element with opactiy to be 100% visible.